# How to Make Kali Linux Terminal Complete Its Suggestions?

Tags: kali-linux

I am using Kali 2021.1. When I type commands in the terminal, it shows my last used command with the portion that I haven't typed grayed out.

For example, when I type `cat`, the terminal outputs the last command that I had typed with `cat`, which was `cat test`, but the test part was grayed out.

[image]

Is there a way for the terminal to autocomplete `test`? If I only type tab, it would not do anything unless I type enough characters in test for it to be singled out from other files that also start with t, te, etc.

Comment: What happens when you hit the right arrow key?

Comment: Yeah… I have no idea what the shell in question is, therefore I'm not going to write an answer. I leave it to you or whomever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the right arrow on your keyboard and it will "harden" the suggested remainder of the command you posted above

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance your Zsh experience by downloading plugins and adding syntax highlighting. To do so, execute the following Git clone commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting
```

Next, open your `.zshrc` file with Nano using `nano ~/.zshrc` and replace the existing `plugins=(git)` line with `plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting)`.

Finally, apply the changes by running `source ~/.zshrc`.